# Cumulative Flow Diagram in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling to find the way to create a Cumulative Flow Diagram with ggplot2 in R. Could find more than commands like geom_area or geom_line or geom_col() options which didn't give me the expected value from the dataset. I have created one with Microsoft Excel (by selective 2d Stacked over line graph) which is attached for your reference. However, I need to transform the same picture (on the left, line graph to right one as CFD).
Anybody can please suggest me what is the best option to do it in R Studio with or with ggplot? I have no problem to use any other package in R, but I need to do it with any of the R package, not with Ms Excel. Thanks in advance. [image]

N.B: I have tried with the geom_area and the code was
`pp <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Year, fill = Entity)) pp + geom_area(stat = "bin") + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")`
but the output was broken as below picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried geom_area?

For example

```
p + geom_area(stat = "bin") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2")`
```

See: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-area-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization

And, please provide a reproducible example. This usually provides you the best answer too!

Comment: Yes, I got that doc link and tried like this: `pp <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Year, fill = Entity))
pp + geom_area(stat = "bin") + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")` and the output has come as some broken bar charts.

Comment: One problem is that the palette provides fewer colours than you need - see here how you can expand it: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2013/09/how-to-expand-color-palette-with-ggplot-and-rcolorbrewer/